# Bitcoin-Core Wallet from 2013

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet-import

Found old wallet.dat file /2013/ , and placed it in a last version Bitcoin-core wallet /synched/.
It shows transactions , but none of them are Confirmed. Are those funds lost forever , or there is smth  i can do about it ?  Thanks in Advance !

Comment: I would enter the transaction IDs into a blockchain explorer to discover their true state.

Comment: Could you describe in a bit more detail what you did? Did you use the `loadwallet` RPC, or did you place it in your bitcoin folder? Was your Bitcoin Core shut down while you did that? Did you call `-rescan`?

Comment: I found that wallet,dat file  , so i placed it in the bitcoin folder. My bitcoin Core was shut down during that time. I did the rescan twice. Most interesting part : today i placed it in Litecoin Core wallet , the same way i did it with Bitcoin one , and imagine........it shows again some funds in it - this time LTC !!!